# for loop not working as expected with variable in ksh

Tags: shell, ksh

The following piece of code is printing /home/user/dir/**@(${host}|${hostname})** instead of printing each of the files in the directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

host=foo
hostname=bar 
config_path="/home/user/dir"

search=$config_path/*_@(${host}|${hostname})_*

for file in $search
do                    
  echo $file
done
```

And It works if I do like this

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

host=foo
hostname=bar 
config_path="/home/user/dir"

#search=$config_path/*_@(${host}|${hostname})_*

for file in $config_path/*_@(${host}|${hostname})_*
do                    
  echo $file
done
```

I've three questions.

1) Why its returning the string when pattern is assigned to variable?

2) I'm using this pattern in so many places, so it's better to assign it a variable. How to fix this?

3) Is it fixed in the newer version of ksh?

I'm using SunOS server 5.10 Generic_147441-23 i86pc i386 i86pc and got ksh version by typing the following command.

```
$ set -o vi
$ Version M-11/16/88i
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this, you can do:

```
for file in $(eval echo $search)
```